# Is the DF flag always set for TCP SYN packets?

Tags: tcp

I wonder if the Don't Fragment flag is always set for TCP SYN packets.

By looking at some Wireshark captures this seems to be the case and according to [Benefits of "Don't Fragment" on TCP Packets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779198/benefits-of-dont-fragment-on-tcp-packets) the "DF flag is typically set on IP packets carrying TCP segments".

Is there a RFC about that?

Comment: There wouldn't be any point. The SYN packages carry no data so they aren't big enough to fragment in the first place.

Comment: That's right, but I would like to know if it is somewhere stated. Also I would like to know if there are some OSes that don't set the DF flag.

Comment: PS: TCP SYN packets may carry data (see RFC 7413 (TCP Fast Open))

Comment: You'd like to know if what is somewhere stated? RFC 793 states that SYN packets don't carry data, or at least implies it. RFC 7413 is experimental.